# without any vpn and router how can resolve this issue

Tags: database, networking, webserver, vpn, router

I have 1 web server and 1 database server. Both located into different geographical location and both are into different network segment and both server have internet ip binding.

So both have directly access via any machine. But there are latency and performance issue while communicating each other.

So without any vpn and router how can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If there are latency issues caused by being in different geographical locations, your options may be limited.
If latency is caused by undesired routing, through whatever geographic locations or poor infrastructure, a vpn can help avoid these issues, but since you don't want VPN you would want another form of tunnelling.

This is assuming that the problem is the quality of the connection between them.

One way to improve overall performance would be to reduce the number of times you need to connect to the database through caching on the app/web server, if possible.

Specifics would require more detailed information about your infrastructure.

Search: memcached